# Animate parent view and child view at same time

Tags: android, animation, material-components-android

If the parentView animation is finished (delay >> duration) there is not glitch.

```
childView.show(x, y, duration = 600, delay = 450)
parentView.show(x, y, duration = 300, isBackground = true)
```

[image: No glitch]

If the parentView view animation is not finished (delay << duration) I got this glitch.

```
childView.show(x, y, duration = 600, delay = 150)
parentView.show(x, y, duration = 600, isBackground = true)
```

[image: Glitch]

Comment: What is `show`?

Comment: A circle reveal animation

Answer (score 0):

You need to sync your animations together. [AnimationSets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet) is exactly what you need. [Here is an example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.view.animation.AnimationSet).

Comment: I am testing it. Is there a way to add a delay between animators? I am using this:             animator2.startDelay = 5000 but both animators start at the same time (animator1 hasn't delay).

Comment: playSequentially wait to the first animator is finished (and I get a glitch in some situations), I think I need a way to add a delay with playTogether